# Unable to take a snapshot of a database which contain "-" in its name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Server database named `db-pwapp-lostandfound-dev`, and I want to take a snapshot of it, but I am getting this error - seems like SQL Server does not like `-` in the name:

[image]

I tried to surround the name by `[]`, but I still have the same issue:

[image]

Any advice ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with quotes?

Comment: what is your SQL  server version ?? i create a db with dash in name and create snapshot without problems in SQL Server 14 with this cmd `CREATE DATABASE Test_Snapshot ON 
(NAME = [Test-db] , FILENAME = 'H:\StackOverFlow\Test_DB_SS.ss')
AS SNAPSHOT OF [Test-db]`

Comment: @DávidLaczkó yes did not work

Comment: @MahdiRahimi THE VERSION IS `ms sql AZURE rtm  - 12.0.2000.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using Azure SQL Database, and it does not support CREATE DATABASE AS SNAPSHOT.

Comment: thanks for the info.. so how i can achieve what i am looking for then?

Comment: I have no idea what you are looking for `:-)`. You will need to elaborate

Comment: Note! If you want to manage the server fully, then why did you selected to use a fully managed platform as a service (PaaS) database? The basic idea of using a fully managed service is that it is managed = meaning that someone else (Microsoft) manages it for you. All backups are managed automatically by Microsoft when you sue Azure SQL DATAABSE.

Comment: now this what the customer chose .. i do not have the ability to change this at this stage

Comment: i created another thread for what i need exactly @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594385/what-i-can-do-to-take-a-cop-snapshot-of-azure-sql-database-before-performing-som

Comment: So, what is the problem?!? Tell your costumer that everything is working well and Microsoft incharge on the back of the database, since he choose to use a service which is fully managed platform as a service (PaaS)

Comment: `i created another thread for what i need exactly` : so, please close this thread `:-)`. You got the direct answer for the question and now we can discuss the needs in the new thread